# Characterizing linear functions

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear if $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) \quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x) \quad \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R} \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. It is known that all linear functions are of the form $f(x) = Ax$, being $A$ a matriz of dimension $n\times m$. How can I prove this? I see that if $f(x) = Ax$, then the definition of linear function is satisfied because of the properties of matrices. How about the converse? It is clear that $f(0)=0$ (taking $y=-x$),but I don't know what should I do. Is it obvious in the case $n=m=1$?

Comment: Fix a basis of $\mathbb R^n$, one of $\mathbb R^m$, and expand $f(x)$.

Comment: @blamethelag I can't believe I didn't see it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear map. Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ be the standard basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$. Then for every $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$ there exist unique $c_1,\ldots,c_n\in\Bbb{R}^n$ such that
$$x=c_1e_1+\ldots+c_ne_n.$$
Because $f$ is linear it follows that
$$f(x)=c_1f(e_1)+\ldots+c_nf(e_n).$$
So it suffices to find a matrix $A$ such that
$$Ae_k=f(e_k),$$
for $1\leq k\leq n$. Of course this is just the matrix with the column vectors $f(e_k)\in\Bbb{R}^m$ as its columns.